# The difference of distances from a point on hyperbola and foci (exercise $13.25.12$ in Tom Apostol's Calculus vol. $1$)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, conic-sections

The exercise $13.25.12$ asks us to prove that on each branch of a hyperbola $\|X - F\| - \|X+F\| = constant$.

From previous discussions, we know that $\|X-F\| = |eXN - a|$ (equation $13.29$ in the book), $a = \frac{ed}{1 - e^2} < 0$ (section $13.22$), $e > 1$ (because it's hyperbola).

If we take $N = (1, 0)$ and $X = (x, y)$, then $XN = x$, so we get $\|X-F\| = |ex-a|$ and by having $-X$ in that equation, we get $\|X+F\| = |ex+a|$. Because it's hyperbola, I suppose we can assume that $|ex| < |a|$.

If that's all correct, then have two cases, one for each hyperbola branch:

Case 1. $ex > 0$ (right branch). $a < 0 < ex \implies 0 < ex - a \implies \|X-F\| = ex-a$. Similarly $-a < ex \implies 0 < ex + a \implies  \|X+F\| = ex+a$. Taking the difference, we get $\|X - F\| - \|X+F\| = ex - a - ex - a = -2a > 0$.

Case 2. $ex < 0$ (left branch). $ex < a \implies ex - a < 0 \implies \|X-F\| = a-ex$. Similarly $ex < -a \implies ex + a < 0 \implies  \|X+F\| = -ex-a$. Taking the difference, we get $\|X - F\| - \|X+F\| = a - ex + ex + a = 2a < 0$.

Did I make a mistake in the proof? Is the first difference positive, because the reference focal point is in the left branch of the hyperbola, as we started with $a < 0$?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have that book at hand and several things are not clear: what is point $N$? what do you mean by $XN$, the scalar product? are foci at $F$ and $-F$? and, above all, what is the definition of hyperbola? Please explain.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca $N$ is a unit vector normal to the directrix. $XN$ is the scalar product of a point $X$ on hyperbola and $N$. Yes, foci are at $F$ and $-F$. The hyperbola is defined as $\|X-F\| = e \cdot distance(X, L)$, where $e > 1$ is the eccentricity, and $L$ is the directrix.